# How to use LIKE for mysql search with ORDER BY the count of most existence keyword in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-like

For example the table name is "test_table"
The text-field name is test-text

```
    $search="internet";
    -----------------
    SELECT text-field  FROM test_table as t
    WHERE (t.text-fielde LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
    ORDER BY MAX(COUNT(XXX))  // xxx=result of LIKE  for $search
```

I hope you got my mean. 
I wana sortet result by number of searched word.

Comment: I could not use it. tnx anyway :)

Comment: Isnt this question confusing? I mean i have three fields and one of them contains internet, then the count is always going to be 1 is it not? Then how will max work in that case ?